# IB Action cannot catch my button click events

Tags: ios, objective-c

IB Action cannot catch my event after clicking , setting button identity as buttonEn , setting en as touchUPInside event method ...But there is still no response fired.

The below is my code:

```
- (IBAction)en:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"enter");
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_en.xls" ofType:@"xls"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    QZWorkbook *excelReader = [[QZWorkbook alloc] initWithContentsOfXLS:url];
    NSArray *sheets =excelReader.workSheets;
    NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < [sheets count] ; i ++){
    QZWorkSheet *sheet = [sheets objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *columns = [ sheet columns];
        NSArray *rows =  columns.firstObject;
        for(int  j = 0  ; j < [rows count] ; j ++){
           QZCell *nextObject =  [ rows objectAtIndex:j ] ;
            [words addObject:            nextObject.content ];
        }
    }
 //   buttonDe.se

    [buttonEn setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonDe setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:1] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonFr setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:2] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonEp setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:3] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonNd setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:4] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonJp setTitle: [words objectAtIndex:5] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [label1 setText:[words objectAtIndex:6] ];
    [label2 setText:[words objectAtIndex:7] ];

    QZWorkSheet *firstWorkSheet = excelReader.workSheets.firstObject;
    [firstWorkSheet open];
    NSLog(@"%@", firstWorkSheet.rows.firstObject);
}
```

Comment: Change the method name from en to some other name..Also check with break point. Remove connection and connect again..!with new action name...!

Answer (score 0):

You should check that IBOutlet is properly connected with button and method.
Apply break point on method and check whether pointer coming to method or not.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *test;
}
-(IBAction)en:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

#import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    \[super viewDidLoad\];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    \[super didReceiveMemoryWarning\];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)en:(id)sender {

//    NSLog(@"enter");
//    NSString *filePath = \[\[NSBundle mainBundle\] pathForResource:@"test_en.xls" ofType:@"xls"\];
//    NSURL *url = \[NSURL URLWithString:filePath\];
//    QZWorkbook *excelReader = \[\[QZWorkbook alloc\] initWithContentsOfXLS:url\];
//    NSArray *sheets =excelReader.workSheets;
//    NSMutableArray *words = \[\[NSMutableArray alloc\] init\];
//    
//    for(int i = 0 ; i < \[sheets count\] ; i ++){
//        QZWorkSheet *sheet = \[sheets objectAtIndex:i\];
//        NSArray *columns = \[ sheet columns\];
//        NSArray *rows =  columns.firstObject;
//        for(int  j = 0  ; j < \[rows count\] ; j ++){
//            QZCell *nextObject =  \[ rows objectAtIndex:j \] ;
//            \[words addObject:            nextObject.content \];
//        }
//    }
//    //   buttonDe.se
//    
//    \[buttonEn setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:0\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    \[buttonDe setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:1\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    \[buttonFr setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:2\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    \[buttonEp setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:3\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    \[buttonNd setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:4\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    \[buttonJp setTitle: \[words objectAtIndex:5\] forState: UIControlStateNormal\];
//    
//    \[label1 setText:\[words objectAtIndex:6\] \];
//    \[label2 setText:\[words objectAtIndex:7\] \];
//    
//    QZWorkSheet *firstWorkSheet = excelReader.workSheets.firstObject;
//    \[firstWorkSheet open\];
//    NSLog(@"%@", firstWorkSheet.rows.firstObject);
}
@end
```

Just create one test project and copy paste this code and link button on IBOutlet with name and method.If this work fine then something is wrong with your implementation.

Comment: the method does not go there.

Answer (score 0):

First drag an UIButton from object library into storyboard or xib.

Then click on assistance editor. middle tab in top right corner.

Then drag button connection up to[image] your .h class of the file where you have to implement button action. Then change connection type outlet to action, set button action method name, and event then connect button.

Button action method will be appear in your .m file

For cross checking print hello button in your method action

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"hello button");
}
```

And remove unnecessary button relative code from your .m file

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I can't change the connection because dragging buttons to the header file with blue line has no response for adding UIButton details

Comment: ok for that you have to set manually header file click on automatic tab this tab will be appear on the middle when you split tab by pressing assistance editor.